# Group values in NxN matrix into a N/2 x N/2 matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Let's assume I have the following 4x4 matrix:

```
import numpy as np
np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
          [5, 6, 7, 8],
          [9,10,11,12],
          [13,14,15,16]])
```

I wish to group the values in 2x2 submatrices, sum them and gather the result in a 2x2 matrix, so that the result in this case would be:

```
[
[14, 22],
[46, 54]
]
```

What is the most numpy-ish way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.reshape` method and then sum along axis:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                 [5, 6, 7, 8],
                 [9,10,11,12],
                 [13,14,15,16]])

bs = 2 #block size
data_r = data.reshape(bs,bs,bs,bs)
data_r
array([[[[ 1,  2],
         [ 3,  4]],
        [[ 5,  6],
         [ 7,  8]]],
       [[[ 9, 10],
         [11, 12]],
        [[13, 14],
         [15, 16]]]])

data_r.sum(axis=(1,3))
array([[14, 22],
       [46, 54]])
```